# Using inherited overloaded methods

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, numbers, integer

I have two classes:

```
public class ClassA {
    public void method(Number n) {
        System.out.println("ClassA: " + n + " " + n.getClass());
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {            
    public void method(Integer d) {
        System.out.println("ClassB: " + d + " " + d.getClass());
    }
}
```

But when I run:

```
ClassA a = new ClassB(); 
a.method(3);
```

I get:

```
ClassA: 3 class java.lang.Integer
```

My question is, why isn't `ClassB`'s method being used?  `a` is an instance of `ClassB`, and `ClassB`'s `method()` has an `Integer` parameter...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> My question is, why isn't ClassB's method being used?

Not true. The method used is `ClassB`'s method, which it inherited from `ClassA`.

---

I think the main reason behind the confusion here is the fact that the method actually is not **overridden**, instead it is **overloaded**. Although `Integer` is a subtype of `Number`, since *method parameter is invariant* in Java, the method `public void method(Integer d)` doesn't override the method `public void method(Number n)`. So, `ClassB` ends up having two (overloaded) methods.

Static binding is used for overloaded methods, and the method with most specific parameter type is chosen by the compiler. But in this case, why does the compiler pick `public void method(Number n)` instead of `public void method(Integer d)`. That's because of the fact that the reference that you are using to invoke the method is of type `ClassA`.

```
ClassA a = new ClassB(); //instance is of ClassB (runtime info)
a.method(3);             //but the reference of type ClassA (compiletime info)
```

The only method that `ClassA` has is `public void method(Number n)`, so that's what the compiler picks up. Remember, here the expected argument type is `Number`, but the actual argument, the integer 3, passed is auto-boxed to the type `Integer`. And the reason that it works is because the *method argument is covariant* in Java.

Now, I think it's clear why it prints

> ClassA: 3 class java.lang.Integer

Comment: I feel like this might be the reason, could you expand a little on your last paragraph?

Comment: @FedeRico: I updated it, hope it helps you understand what's going on.

Comment: I think that this answer (so far) has been the clearest as to what is going on. The key here is that the binding for a method invocation is resolved during *compilation* and is dependent upon the *declared type* of the variable. The *declared type* is `ClassA` and therefore the method ClassB#method(Integer) is unavailable for selection. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1 - under the bullet point "In all other cases, the qualified name has the form FieldName . Identifier."

Comment: @BheshGurung Perfect.  I was confused as I had only seen examples where both methods had the exact same signature, so then the sub-method would override the super-method and get called instead (even with a ClassB instance in a ClassA variable).  Thank you and everyone else for your help!

Comment: How do you reconcile your mutually contradictory statements that he is 'not overloading the method' but also has 'actually overloaded the method'?

Comment: @GargantChet: Thanks for the edit, to fix what EJP was pointing out.

Comment: @EJP: I wasn't trying to contradict myself. :) That was a typo, which has been fixed by GargantChet. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 10):

Your issue stems from the fact that (as quoted from the official Java tutorials on Inheritance):

> In a subclass, you can overload the methods inherited from the superclass. Such overloaded methods neither hide nor override the superclass methods—they are new methods, unique to the subclass.`

Refer to the official Java tutorials for more details:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Yes, I read this article before posting this, I still cant't understand why B's method isn't being used, as it has an Integer parameter which is more suited for the value being used, 3.

Comment: Agreed. But, consider that in your case the Number and Integer method arguments are considered to be two completely different signatures - meaning that ClassB (the inherited class) has those methods available to it when called. Or as @rbhawsar said, `number 3 is automatically boxed to Integer` in [his reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832055/using-inherited-overloaded-methods/12832107#12832107)

Comment: I understand this, at the moment method() is called, the variable "a", of class ClassB, has two methods "available" for use, one receiving an Integer, and another one inherited from ClassA that receives a Number.  What I don't (unfortunately) understand is why, having the Integer-cast-"3", ClassB's method(Integer d) isn't being used (even if the other one is also available).

Comment: @FedeRico: Overload resolution is done at **compile time**, not at run-time! Since, at compile time, the type of `a` is `ClassA`, there is only *one* method "available" for use.

Answer (score 6):

a is of type ClassA so the methods in ClassB **will not be visible** to instance a unless it is declared as ClassB

```
ClassB a = new ClassB();
```

will produce your expected output. Number is the supertype of Integer. So whatever you pass in will be autoboxed to appropriate subtype and the method in ClassA will be called. Try passing

```
a.method(3.0f) // Float
a.method(3.0) // Double
```

Answer (score 4):

Because Number and Integer in the arguments creates two different method signatures. So, class B just has two different methods that are available to use.

Answer (score 4):

because number 3 is automatically boxed to Integer.

please see the link below:
    http://www.javabeat.net/articles/print.php?article_id=31

General Rule: Arguments are implicitly widened to match method parameters.
It's not legal to widen from one wrapper class to another.

Comment: Yes, but the method using an Integer argument is in ClassB, that's why I don't understand why ClassA method is being used.

Comment: ClassB has both the methods. as per inheritance. and since you have created the object of B method of B is called. because its decided at runtime which method will be called.

Comment: So "3" is automatically boxed to Integer, which is then sent to the method taking Number as a parameter, instead of Integer? Why would this happen?

Comment: The reason is all the wrapper classes like BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float,Integer, Long, Short extend Number class and its not valid to say Integer IS-A Long.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two operations have different argument (parameter) types (Even though they are subclasses) they are considered different (Unlike C) you did not override the first method with the second one. Instead you ended up with class B which now has two methods

```
 public void method(Number n)  and
 public void method(Integer n)
```

by default when you did a.method(3)   3 was casted to an Integer object. 
You can verify this by calling

```
a.method((Number)3);      //this would call the second method/operation.
```

You can also verify this by using reflection to iterate on class B's methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
  class ClassA
  {
     public void method( Number n )
     {
        System.out.println( "ClassA: " + n + " " + n.getClass() );
     }// void method( Number n )

  }// class ClassA

  public class ClassB
     extends
        ClassA
  {
     public void method( Integer d )
     {
        System.out.println( "ClassB: " + d + " " + d.getClass() );
     }// void method( Integer d )

     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
        ClassB b = new ClassB(); 
        ClassA a = b; 
        a.method( new Integer( 3 )); // 1. ClassA: 3 class java.lang.Integer
        b.method( new Integer( 4 )); // 2. ClassB: 4 class java.lang.Integer
        b.method( new Float( 5.6 )); // 3. ClassA: 5.6 class java.lang.Float
     }// void main( String[] args )

  }// class ClassB
```

1. Since the two methods are NOT overloaded and the instance is of class a, no dispatch occurs from A to B
2. B has a best match method, then it's chosen
3. B can't handle a parameter of type Float, so A method is chosen

Comment: Is there a reason both methods are not being overloaded? (they have different signatures)

Comment: Yes, because they have different signatures. A signature is the name of the function plus the types of the parameters (the type of returned value is ignored).

Answer (score 1):

To clear I added, `show()` method in both `classA` and `classB`.

```
public void show() {
        System.out.println(getClass());
    }
```

I call like this,

```
    // Case 1       
    ClassA a = new ClassB();
    a.method(3);// ClassA: 3 class java.lang.Integer
    a.show(); // class ClassB

    // Case 2       
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    b.method(3);// ClassB: 3 class java.lang.Integer
    b.show(); // class ClassB
```

> Here method(Number n) and method(Integer d) have different signatures.
>   It is  not overriding. It is overloading.
>
> But show() method is method overriding.

In case 1, 
**Only methods of class A are accessible with object a. a is type classA, methods in classB are not visible.**
That's why your classA method is called.
But for show() method as it is overridden method, class B's show() method is called.

In case 2, 
Both methods of class A and B are accessible with object b as ClassB extends ClassA.

Answer (score 0):

You had the following code

```
Class A a = new ClassB(); 
a.method(3);
```

But imagine you have a method where "a" and "3" are passed to you as a parameter and you still execute the same code

```
public void foo(A a, Number n)
{
    a.method(n);
}
```

The compiler does not know whether you are going to pass Class A or Class B (or Number or Integer). It must still resolve the method so it can do type checking for the return value from a.method

Answer (score 0):

I did some R&D on this problem and come up with solution to remove your confusion. Hopefully it will help you to understand.

Look for some below code:

```
class A {
    public void func(Number obj){
        System.out.println("In a func");
    }
    public void func(Integer obj){
        System.out.println("In b func");        
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

public class X {

    public static void main(String s[]){
        B b = new B();
        b.func(3);

        A a = new B();
        a.func(3);
    }
}
```

If you will run this code you will get output: 

**"In b func"**

**"In b func"**.

In this case, here are 4 methods:

1. class A is having both the overloaded methods: func(Number)[say method 1] and func(Integer)[say method 2]
2. class B is also having 2 methods because of inheritance. So it has func(Number)[say method 3] and func(Integer)[say method 4]

Now when you call b.func(3) on reference of B, it will see the "method 3" and "method 4", which have parameter with most fit derived class. Here both Number and Integer classes are fit for argument **3**, but Integer is derived from Number, so func(Integer)[method 3] will be called. Hence the output is "In b func"

Second output is also "In b method", because of same logic.
First remember, you can not call any method on class A reference which class A is not having. So you can only call those methods on reference of class A which it have. No matter the instance is of class A or it's subclass's instance.

You need to understand it in 2 terms, compilation and linking and execution.

Now Class A is having both the methods, so when compiler look a.func(3) on reference of class A. Compiler will look into "methods 1" and "method 2" of class A and bind the method signature which have arguments with most fit derived class. So is "func(Integer)".

Now at run time, func(Integer) will be executed, it is called of class B, because instance is of class B. (At runtime, method is executed from the class, whose instance is calling the method). So method 4 is called. Hence the output.

I am sure, you will have confusion, why method 2 is not called and method 4 is called.

If you will run below code:

```
class A {
    public void func(Number obj){
        System.out.println("In a func");
    }
    public void func(Integer obj){
        System.out.println("In b func");        
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void func(Number obj){
        System.out.println("In a func of class B");
    }
    public void func(Integer obj){
        System.out.println("In b func of class B");     
    }
}

public class X {

    public static void main(String s[]){
        B b = new B();
        b.func(3);

        A a = new B();
        a.func(3);
    }
}
```

Output will be:

**In b func of class B

In b func of class B**

Now you can understand this code with above explanation. Either we have called fun(3) on reference of class A or class B. Each time class B's method is called (method 4). Because the instance is of class B. But if class A will not have (method 2). Method 4 will not be called on "a.func(3)"

Lets have a look on below code:

```
class A {
    public void func(Number obj){
        System.out.println("In a func");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void func(Integer obj){
        System.out.println("In b func");        
    }
}
public class X {

    public static void main(String s[]){
        B b = new B();
        b.func(3);

        A a = new B();
        a.func(3);
    }
}
```

Output of this program is:

**In b func

In a func**

Now you may have confusion why is it different output?

Remember, here are not 4 methods. Here are only 3 methods:

1. func(Number) in class A
2. func(Number) in class B, inherited from class A
3. func(Integer) in class B

Now if you call a.fun(3), class A is not having func(Integer), and you can not call method on reference of class A which class not have. So compiler will not bind func(Integer) because there is no such method in class A. But there is another method func(Number) which can be called with the same code a.func(3) Autoboxing concept of java.

So when a.func(3) called, it basically call func(Number). Now because the instance is of class B, method func(Number) of class B is called. Hence the output is "In a func"

This is a very big answer, but I explained in deep, so you can easily understand different possibilities of outputs in different usecases.

Enjoy coding!

Answer (score -1):

In overloading, method resolution always takes care by compiler based on reference type. So, In overloading runtime object[new ClassB()] does not play any role.
Therefore, in your case the method of ClassA was executed.

```
ClassA a = new ClassB(); 
a.method(3);
```