# Hiding vs. overloading in C++/Java?

Tags: java, c++, inheritance

Here's what i remembered:

In C++, if derived class defines a member function with the same name, but different signature (parameter etc) than the base class, it'll 'hide' the corresponding member function in base. e.g.

```
class Base {
public:
  void virtual f(double x); 
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void f(char c); 
};

int main()
{
  Derived* d = new Derived();
  Base* b = d;
  b->f(65.3);  // call f(double x)
  d->f(65.3);  // call f(char c)
  delete d;
  return 0;
}
```

correct me if i am wrong, but i think in C++ by saying 'hide', it also means Derived class **can not see 'f(double x)'**, or in other words, Derived do not have 'f(double x)' as its inherited member function from Base, correct?

In Java tutorial, 'hide' actually means something else (for static class method), whereas for instance method, you can overload the method inherited from base. Looking at this example: [Using inherited overloaded methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832055/using-inherited-overloaded-methods)

```
public class ClassA {
    public void method(Number n) {
        System.out.println("ClassA: " + n + " " + n.getClass());
    }
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {            
    public void method(Integer d) {
        System.out.println("ClassB: " + d + " " + d.getClass());
    }
}

ClassA a = new ClassB(); 
a.method(3);
```

In C++ type of thinking, i would get the same result that 'method(Number n)' from Class A is called, based on 'dynamic binding' and 'hiding' idea in C++, but:

1. I am still not sure how to explain it in Java. The link itself explains using 'method signature is chosen at compile time' and 'it is actually calling from Class B'; but in C++ thinking, the former is OK, but i do not think it's calling from Class B, it should be calling from Class A, right?
2. In [Using inherited overloaded methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832055/using-inherited-overloaded-methods) and Java tutorial, 'Class B' is allowed to overload function from 'Class A', and 'Class B' actually can see **both** 'method(Number n)' and 'method(Integer d)'. So C++ and Java are treating overloading differently, right? And why is that? Say in the C++ example, if Derived also allow overloading, 'd->f(65.3)' would call 'f(double x)', not 'f(char c)'.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In C++ every thing is static for non-virtual functions, so for non-virtual functions you don't have `dynamic-binding`. And hiding do not remove function from inheritance. It's something like this:

When you define method `M` as: `void M(int)` then compiler implement a function internally name `Base::M` as `void Base::M( Base* this, int )`. Now this function is implemented somewhere in code and can't removed and you can call it as long as you be able to provide a this (actually you can call it without even having this). So in `Child` I can call `Base::M(0);` and C++ convert `this` from `Child*` to `Base*` and call `M`. When you define a function with its name correspond to the name of base class you tell the compiler that I prefer to use that name in my class for a new method or property! But you don't remove any thing and you can use `using` to bring old definition of `M` to `Child`:

```
struct Base {
    void f( int ) {}
};
struct Child : Base {
    void f( char* ) {}
    using Base::f;  // Bring Base::f to this class, so I have f(char*), f(int)
};
```

And beside that you can call `f(int)` without even use of `using`.

```
// In the Child class
void test() {
    Base::f('c');  // Call Base::f(char)
}

// Outside of class
Child c;
((Base*)&c)->f('1');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how I would expect C++ to behave. Rather than hiding the base class method, I would expect the subclass to simply overload the method because the parameters are different. Thus, the compiler will know which method to use when you call b->f() because there's only one available, but it has to work out which one to use when you call d->f() based in your parameter type. If it can't then at compile time you will be forced to use a cast. With your example it should recognise the decimal point and use double instead if char.

Comment: Oh no, hang on! I think the virtual qualifier is important here. Basically C++ seems to allow you to not-quite-override a virtual function by changing its method signature in your subclass implementation. This is weird and I would avoid it if possible!

Comment: No, virtual isn't important. You can just as well declare an `int f;` in the derived class to hide the name from the base class. A derived class acts like an inner scope, new declarations hide similar names from outer scopes.