# Code Snippet involving Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

The code I am running is as follows :

```
public class Triangle {   
     public void draw() { 
         System.out.println("Base::draw\n");  
     }  
     public void computeCentroid(Triangle t) {  
         System.out.println("Base::centroid");
     }
}


class RightAngledTr extends Triangle {  
    public void draw() { 
       System.out.println("RightAngle::draw\n" );  
    }  
    public void computeCentroid(RightAngledTr t) {
       System.out.println("RtAngle::centroid");    
    } 
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Triangle tr= new RightAngledTr();
    RightAngledTr rtr= new RightAngledTr();  
    tr.computeCentroid(tr); 
    tr.draw(); 
    tr.computeCentroid(rtr);
}
```

The output this gives is as follows :

```
Base::centroid
RightAngle::draw
Base::centroid
```

I don't understand the reason behind the third output line. 
My doubt : 
tr.computeCentroid(rtr) should call the method of Derived class RightAngledTr(since the parameter passed is rtr). Hence print : RtAngle::centroid

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know I have already answered the question. Upon doing search I found the duplicate question to be the best matching duplicate to this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void computeCentroid(RightAngledTr t)
```

and

```
public void computeCentroid(Triangle t)
```

have different method signatures, so there is no override here, at all.

Answer (score 2):

Class `RightAngledTr` does **not** override the method but **overload** since Java method is invariant.

Class `RightAngledTr` has 2 methods essentially, one requiring `Triangle` and the other `RightAngledTr`) so by specifying the *most specific* parameter, the JVM knows which methods to invoke by matching the parameter type to the most specific method matching it.

See more:

- [JLS 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832055/using-inherited-overloaded-methods)

Comment: So, the call tr.computeCentroid(rtr); should invoke computeCentroid of RightAngledTr and print RightAngle::centroid. But it prints base::centroid.

Comment: No true, `tr.computeCentroid` has only 1 method so the *most specific method` is with a `Triangle` parameter and since `rtr` *IS A* `Triangle`, it matches. See the updated post on what the JLS states on choosing the most specific method.

Answer (score 0):

For `RightAngledTr.computeCentroid` to override `Triangle.computeCentroid` it must have a matching parameter declaration. But yours does not. If you change your declaration in `RightAngledTr` to:

```
@Override
public void computeCentroid(Triangle t)
```

Then you will see the behavior you expect. Note the use of `@Override`, which will help you identify this issue in the future.